# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timepicker

I've been reading through the answers on here but nothing seems to be working on their solutions, for some reason I am getting a console error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'" when I am using a button to load up the script using fancybox, but the crazy thing is. If I natively call the function using JavaScript through the calendar we are using directly it works fine, but we would like it to work on the button, which it previously did before the installation of new plugins.

```
$('#Time').datetimepicker({
datepicker:false,
format:'H:i',
step:30,
minTime: '07:00',
maxTime: '21:00'
```

});

Anyone have any ideas? The HTML is below

```
<tr>
<td>Time:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="Time" name="Time" value="<?php
if(isset($Time)) echo $Time; ?>" class="inputBoxSmall time" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Update: I've just noticed this -> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery-ui.min.js:5

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js">   </script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: datetimepicker is not part of jQuery. You need to include jQuery UI and specific datetimepicker plugin

Comment: did you include the datetimepicker library

Comment: Hi I have just updated the code question, thanks

Comment: @NickyThomas include jQuery UI **after** jQuery and include datetimepicker plugin after both. Check `requirements` part: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: @A.Wolff - that fixed the jQuery is not defined thanks, although the timepicker is error still seems to be there.

Comment: @NickyThomas but have you include datetimepicker??? I guess not

Comment: @A.Wolff yes it has been included :) Full JS scripts can be seen below

`<!-- Remote JS -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Local JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/base.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Jquery is the base source file and jQuery UI uses the jQuery source file. So the order of the including script has to be reversed.  And secondly i guess you are using jQuery DateTimePicker plugin. `"A jQuery plugin is simply a new method that we use to extend jQuery's prototype object"`.The idea of a plugin is to do something with a collection of elements. Usually almost all plugins comes with a separate js file and if needed a stylesheet also. So in your case

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="path to your datepicker plugin here"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to your plugin style sheet here"/>
```

You can see working examples [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the order is correct now although I am using
jquery-timepicker v1.2.13 - http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: Oh wow a massive oversight! Thanks for the help this has fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are including scripts in the wrong order.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js">   </script>
```

jQuery must come before jQuery UI.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the jQuery error - will keep that in mind in the future. Although the timepicker error is still present 

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'

<!-- Remote JS -->
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--Local JS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/base.js"></script>`

Comment: @NickyThomas check path to jquery.timepicker.js, have you got a 404 error or any other error in console? If none, please consider to share an online link which replicates your issue to let us check